# Can we say "Don't be hard" on a physical objects like toys or chairs rather than on parts of a body?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

According to Oxford Dictionary

> **[be hard on somebody/something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hard_1?q=hard)**: ​to be likely to hurt or damage something
>
> Looking at a computer screen all day can be very hard on the eyes.

The dictionary says we can use "**be hard on something**" and they don't state clearly what something must be.

But most dictionaries often give example like "[be very hard on the eyes](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hard_1?q=hard)" or "[This kind of work can be hard on your back.](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/hard)" or "[Aerobics is quite hard on the knees.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-hard-on-something)"

So the "**something**" here often refers to parts of a body like "**your eyes/ back/knees etc**".

My question is

Can the "**something**" be a non-human physical objects like a table, a chair, toys, or  a bowl or things like that?

For example, when a boy tried to pull, crumple, and twist a rubber toy car, can we say "**don't be hard on your toy car**"?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the object of the verb “hard on” can be people, animals, or inanimate objects.

> Off-road racing is hard on a motorcycle

> The training sergeant was hard on the platoon

> She was a gentle rider with light hands, never hard on her mount